# Why the function strlen() returns different values for the same length of two char arrays?

Tags: c, arrays, strlen

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {
    
    char a[50],b[50];// same sized arrays

    for(int j =0;j<50;j++){
        b[j]='b';a[j]='a';// initializing with the same number of elements
    }

    printf("the size of a is %ld,",strlen(a));
    printf("the size of B is %ld",strlen(b));

    return 0;
}
```

> The output is
>
> **the size of a is 50,
> the size of B is 54**

But what i expect is **the size of a is 50
the size of B is 50**

what is the problem here?

Comment: `a` and `b` are not _strings_ as they both lack a _null character_ as required by `strlen()`.

Comment: This is [your code in action](https://www.jdoodle.com/embed/v0/25x8)

Comment: I also thought of coincidence and tried several times.

Comment: @isrnick - I agree that this is undefined behavior.

Comment: `GCC 5.3.0` produces what OP described, `GCC 9.1.0` - gives the same value of 54 for both..

Comment: An array of size `N` can store at maximum a string with `N-1` non-null characters plus the null character that signals the end of the string. So, since your arrays have size 50, your for loop should go up to `j<49`, and after the loop there should be assignments of the null characters to position 49 in both arrays `b[49]='\0'; a[49]='\0';` .

Answer (score 1):

> what is the problem here?

The problem is that you don't terminate your strings.

C requires strings to be [null terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string):

> The length of a C string is found by searching for the (first) NUL byte. This can be slow as it takes O(n) (linear time) with respect to the string length. It also means that a string cannot contain a NUL character (there is a NUL in memory, but it is after the last character, not "in" the string).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main() {

    char a[50],b[50];// same sized arrays

    for(int j =0;j<50;j++){
        b[j]='b';a[j]='a';// initializing with the same number of elements
    }

    // Terminate strings
    a[49] = b[49] = 0;

    printf("the size of a is %ld,",strlen(a));
    printf("the size of B is %ld",strlen(b));

    return 0;
}
```

Gives the correct result.

Comment: Note that you are writing characters 'b' and 'a' in the position of index 49 of both arrays inside the loop, and then overwriting it with the null character after exiting the loop.

Comment: it should be a[49]=b[49]='\0'; you've mistakenly typed as a[49]=b[49]=0;

Comment: @FRANCISCASIMIRS `'\0'` and `0` are the same.

Comment: @isrnick Yes this is intentional.